# Creating New Contacts In Bulk AND adding to distros

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a script that creates bulk external contacts using PS and a CSV. I would like to tweak this to not only create the contact but also add the contact to any specified distros.

```
foreach($contact in (import-csv c:\users\ME\desktop\contactstest.csv)){
$properties = @{
    type            = 'Contact'
    name            = $contact.firstname + ", " + $contact.lastname
    OtherAttributes = @{'mail' = "$($contact.email)"}
    Path            = "OU=External Contacts,DC=Company,DC=org"
}

New-ADObject @properties

}
```

If I have the CSV with the following columns. Is this do-able?

Firstname/lastname/email/Group

The CSV is located on the desktop of the DC.

---

**CSV EXAMPLE**

first,last,email,group

billy,bob,bb@aol.com,emailist1

Comment: Add `-PassThru` to the New-ADObject cmdlet and capture the newly created contact. Then use that object in the `-Members` parameter of [Add-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2016-ps)

Comment: I should add that when I'm doing these bulk addition. Some contacts are going to added to more than one group / not all contacts are added to the same group.

Comment: If you have a contact that needs to go into several groups, add these in the `Group` column of the csv, separated by a character like `;`. Then in the code split on that character and do a `ForEach-Object` loop in which you put the `Add-GroupMember` line, using `$_` as Identity parameter.

Comment: Please see my edit, I have added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now what went wrong the first time.
What I meant was for you to **replace** the line `New-ADObject @properties` with my code block. Since you left that in aswell, the code tried to create the contact twice, leading to the error message and skipping the part where it add the contact to the group(s).

If your CSV looks like this:

```
first,last,email,group
billy,bob,bb@aol.com,emailist1
jane,doe,jd@somewhereintheworld.com,emaillist1;emaillist5
```

<sup>Note the second contact is to be added to two groups, separated by a semi-colon `;`</sup>

Here the code in full:

```
foreach ($contact in (import-csv c:\users\ME\desktop\contactstest.csv)) {
    # create a hash table for splatting the parameters to New-ADObject
    $properties = @{
        type            = 'Contact'
        name            = $contact.firstname + ", " + $contact.lastname
        OtherAttributes = @{'mail' = "$($contact.email)"}
        Path            = "OU=External Contacts,DC=Company,DC=org"
    }
    # create the contact and capture the resulting object
    $newContact = New-ADObject @properties -PassThru -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($newContact) {
        # if success, add this contact to the group(s)
        $contact.Group -split ';' | ForEach-Object {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $newContact
        }    
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not create contact $($contact.lastname)"
    }
}
```

P.S. You can also include the PassThru and ErrorAction parameters to the splatting hash:

```
$properties = @{
    type            = 'Contact'
    name            = $contact.firstname + ", " + $contact.lastname
    OtherAttributes = @{'mail' = "$($contact.email)"}
    Path            = "OU=External Contacts,DC=Company,DC=org"
    PassThru        = $true
    ErrorAction     = 'SilentlyContinue'
}
```

Comment: I'm just getting an error that the object is already created (even when I clear the CSV and add a new contact that doesn't already exist in AD) This creates the new contact but does not add to group (despite the message suggesting it could not create the object)

Comment: @someguy2121 you put in all different properties didn't you (name, mail etc.)? Is your csv using a comma as delimiter? (Without specifying, Import-Csv assumes a comma) Are you running this on a DC? If not, it can take some time for all systems to synchronize, so you may not yet see the new object untill a few minutes later..

Comment: I put the code I'm running in an answer because I ran out of characters.

Comment: @someguy2121 don't just copy my answer as new answer.. You didn't answer my questions. Please edit your question and post the first couple of lines of the csv there. Are you using _slashes_ as delimiter character??

Comment: @someguy2121 It was getting very late in my part of the world yesterday, so here my (delayed) updated answer.